# Difference between xticks shown in interactive plots and preview plots in PyCharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I am starting to learn about plots in Python/PyCharm. I found a nice tutorial which uses the following code to give basic idea about labels:

```
# library
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Let's consider a basic barplot.
# Data
bars = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
height = [3, 12, 5, 18, 45]
y_pos = np.arange(len(bars))
# Plot
plt.bar(y_pos, height)

# If we have long labels, we cannot see it properly
names = ("very long group name 1", "very long group name 2", "very long group name 3", "very long group name 4",
         "very long group name 5")
plt.xticks(y_pos, names, rotation=90)

# Thus we have to give more margin
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.4)
# Show the graph
plt.show()
```

The PyCharm plot window opens up and shows the respective plot. But the labels are not displayed correctly:

[image]

As you can see, the x ticks are numbered (0.0 to 4.0), while in the preview window (small picture on the top right) the labels are named correctly. Is there some additional configuration I have to set up? Might the issue be caused by the size of my screen? I am working on MAC Sonoma 14.2.1 and PyCharm 2023.3.2.

The issue only occurs when I am using interactive plots. Onece I turn off interactive plots through PyCharm settings, the labels are shown correctly.